# Quantum field theory, super-renormalizable interactions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Is it really necessary to renormalize a super-renormalizable theory?

Comment: What, ***specifically***,  is your proposal on what to do with the finite # of divergences in them? As it stands, your question is inviting a rambling, impossibly broad essay.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279340/super-renormalizable-theory-and-beta-function).

Comment: i am trying to speculate if we could be better off without renormlization procedure by imposing a finite condition on the correlation functions at a point and hope it works for the rest of the points in position or momentum space.

Comment: what you are suggesting is the renormalization procedure.

Comment: Are you saying that mere introduction of finite conditions, say on the propagators, is enough to designate the procedure as renormalization procedure, even without re-defining the parameters?